# change data to matrix for calculation betweennnes of nodes

Tags: r

I have a csv file.it is 50*50 .i want change this data to matrix for calculation betweennnes of nodes. but error is shown
this link of data 
http://s1.picofile.com/file/8285275142/random001.csv.html

```
w=read.table("C:\Users\tina\Desktop\graph\random001.csv")
library(igraph)
adjm=matrix(w,nc=50)
g1=graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjm,weighted=TRUE)
```

Comment: It's quite unclear how to download your file on this file, cause it's all in Arabic. Please use dropbox or smth like this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `as.matrix` here.

```
w <- read.csv("<path to random001.csv>", header = F)    
adjm <- as.matrix(w)
g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjm, weighted = TRUE)
```

Comment: this error show              
""Error in .Call("R_igraph_graph_adjacency", adjmatrix, as.numeric(mode),  : 
  At structure_generators.c:272 : Non-square matrix, Non-square matrix
In addition: Warning message:
In `mode<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "double") : NAs introduced by coercion""

Comment: I forgot that I read the table in a different way, see the updated answer. In your case the first line goes to column names, so you obtain a non-square matrix.